# Angular directive > Dynamic controller name > Interpolate controller name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need some help on how to pass controllers definitions to `inner` directive nested in `outer` directive. Please see http://plnkr.co/edit/Om2vKdvEty9euGXJ5qan for a (not)working example.

1. Is there any way to make angular interpolate what is passed on `script.js@46` as `item.ctrlName`?
2. How to use `controllerAs` syntax in `inner` directive?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I see you use ctrl-name attribute on the <inner> directive but the `inner` directive doesn't `ctrlName` defined in it's scope.

Comment: @Miszy It's used here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a5ff651a59933c2c43b81642454ee458f98e1401/src/ng/compile.js#L2086 by angular. On my side it's passed through `script.js@64+65`.

Comment: No, it's not. Can you show me which like exactly in angular (?) uses `ctrlName` or `ctrl-name` here? I think this is a typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you need to access parent directive's controller you can just use `require` field on the inner directive.

Comment: `attrs[directive.name]` points to the value of `ctrl-name` attribute through `name: 'ctrlName'` in `inner` directive. That is working OK if I use string value as I did in `script.js@47`. Problem is that I need that to be dynamic/interpolated as stated in `script.js@46`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution going step down (up ?) with the abstraction. I'm dynamically constructing the whole directive configuration object and then lazy registering it.

See http://plnkr.co/edit/pMsgop6u51zPLqkfWaWT

```
angular.module('app', ['moduleLazyLoader'])

.controller('mainCtrl', ['$log', function ($log) {
this.list = [
  {
    name: 'asd',
    ctrl: [
      'ItemAsdCtrl',
      function () {
        $log.debug('ItemAsdCtrl');
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'xyz',
    ctrl: [
      'ItemXyzCtrl',
      function () {
        $log.debug('ItemXyzCtrl');
      }
    ]
  }
];
}])

.directive('outer', ['factoryLazyLoader', '$log', '$compile', function (factoryLazyLoader, $log, $compile) {

function controller () {}

return {
  restrict: 'E',
  controller: controller,
  controllerAs: 'outer',
  bindToController: true,
  scope: {
    list: '=list'
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
    var directives = [];

    scope.outer.list = scope.outer.list.map(function (ele, idx) {

      var directiveSuffix = ele.ctrl[0];

        directiveSuffix[0].toUpperCase();

      var directiveName = 'item' + directiveSuffix,
        directiveAttrName = directiveName.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join("-").toLowerCase();

      directives.push(directiveAttrName);

      factoryLazyLoader.registerDirective([
        directiveName,
        function () {
          return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            controller: ele.ctrl[1],
            controllerAs: ele.ctrl[0],
            bindToController: true,
            template: '<div>{{' + ele.ctrl[0] + ' | json}}</div>',
            scope: {
              item: '=item'
            }
          }
        }
      ])

      return ele;
    });

    var tpl = '<div>';

    angular.forEach(directives, function (val, idx) {
      tpl += '<' + val +' item="outer.list[' + idx + ']">' + '</' + val  + '>';
    });

    tpl += '</div>'

    // debugger;

    element.replaceWith($compile(tpl)(scope))


  }
};
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

1) if you need the inner directive to have the parent controller you can use the require params on the inner directive. Something like this

```
angular.module('docsTabsExample', [])
  .directive('outer', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {},
      templateUrl: '...', // or template
      controllerAs: 'outer',
      bindToController: true,  // This bind the scope with the controller object
      controller: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('inner', function() {
    return {
      require: '^outer',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        title: '@'
      },
      controllerAs: 'inner',
      bindToController: true,  // This bind the scope with the controller object
      templateUrl: '...', // or template
      controller: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
        // tabsCtrl and all the methods on the outer directive
      },
    };
});
```

2) You have set controller: controller and controller is a empty function, but you can set there a function like i did before and make sure of put the  bindToController: true

Comment: thx for your answer. For `1.` what I need is to use some controller other than the `outer` one as a exact controller for `inner`. Using `require:` I can access the `outer` directive controller but then how can I tell `inner` to use outerCtr.list[x].ctrl as it's own controller?

For `2.` It's like you said if using `require:` but can't make it working with `controller: '@', name: 'ctrlName',` combo.

Comment: aah know i get it better. You what to pass distinct controller to every inner directive?. Ok if this is the case, why you want to do that? i think maybe there ir another way to attack that problem, not setting up the controller of the directive, but creating something like a api. where the inner controller have some methods that call the dynamic functions methods. 

Do you know what i meen?